# Incorrect syntax near ',' using TOP

Tags: sql-server

I am not able able to figure out where I am wrong in my simple query.

SQL Server Query:

```
select
    TOP 1 WITH TIES,
    seller_id,
    sum(price) as total
from sales
group by
    seller_id
order by
    total desc
```

Error Message:

> [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

I tried to search online as well but did not get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove redundant `,` after `TIES,`

```
select
    TOP 1 WITH TIES
    seller_id,
    sum(price) as total
from sales
group by
    seller_id
order by
    total desc
```